# Substitute an interface for another one

Tags: go

Recently, I stumbled upon an [interesting article](https://www.perimeterx.com/tech-blog/2019/ok-lets-go/) regarding the organization of Go code.

I was highly interested in the third approach: 'Independent Packages'.
It's said packages should NOT depend on each other, but defines their own interface to interact with
other packages.

Now, I face a problem with the approach.

I'm building a CLI applications that's able to execute various commands, one after each other.
It's important that these commands can share data.

First, I have built a contain in which I can register commands.
This resides in the package: `commands`.

```
import (
    "sync"
)

// PRIVATE: Defines the API for sharing data between different commands.
type context interface {
    SetAPIKey(string)
}

// Command defines the API that a command should satisfy to become eligible for being registered in the container
type Command interface {
    GetName() string
    SetProperty(prop, val string) error
    Execute(context) error
}

// Container exposes the API for registration and retrieving of services.
type Container struct {
    mutex              sync.RWMutex
    registeredCommands map[string]Command
}

// Add adds the command `cmd` to the container.
func (c *Container) Add(cmd Command) {
    c.withLock(func() {
        if c.registeredCommands == nil {
            c.registeredCommands = make(map[string]Command)
        }

        c.registeredCommands[cmd.GetName()] = cmd
    })
}

// Get retrieves the command who's name is equal to `name`.
func (c *Container) Get(name string) Command {
    return c.withRLock(func() Command {
        if c.registeredCommands == nil {
            return nil
        }

        if cmd, ok := c.registeredCommands[name]; ok {
            return cmd
        }

        return nil
    })
}

// PRIVATE: Create a lock and execute the function `handler`.
//          The lock is being released when the function `handler` is executed.
func (c *Container) withLock(handler func()) {
    c.mutex.Lock()
    defer c.mutex.Unlock()

    handler()
}

// PRIVATE: Create a "read" lock and execute the function `handler`.
//          The lock is being released when the function `handler` is executed.
func (c *Container) withRLock(handler func() Command) Command {
    c.mutex.RLock()
    defer c.mutex.RUnlock()

    return handler()
}
```

Next I have command which implements the `Command` interface.
NOTE: This is stored in another package: `rest`.

```
import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "encoding/xml"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

// PRIVATE: Defines the API for sharing data between different commands.
type context interface {
    SetAPIKey(string)
}

// GetAPIKey is the command that allows the retrieval of a API key using the REST API.
type GetAPIKey struct {
}

// GetName returns the name of the command `cmd`.
func (GetAPIKey) GetName() string {
    return "API.REST.getAPIKey"
}

// SetProperty assigns value `val` to property `prop`.
func (cmd *GetAPIKey) SetProperty(prop, val string) error {
    return nil
}

// Execute runs the command.
func (cmd GetAPIKey) Execute(ctx context) error {
    ctx.SetAPIKey(xmlResponse.Key)

    return nil
}
```

The MAIN entry point of the application is defined as follows:

```
// PRIVATE: Defines the container in which all the available commands are registered.
var container commands.Container

// PRIVATE: Defines an API for sharing data between different commands.
type context struct {
    apiKey string
}

func (ctx *context) SetAPIKey(value string) {
    ctx.apiKey = value
}

// PRIVATE: Represents the 'MAIN' entry point for the application.
//          This method is executed when the application is started.
func main() {
    ctx := &context{}
    container := new(commands.Container)
    container.Add(&rest.GetAPIKey{})
    command := container.Get("API.REST.getAPIKey")
    command.SetProperty("baseURI", "")
    command.SetProperty("environmentNameOrURL", "")
    command.SetProperty("userName", "")
    command.SetProperty("password", "")

    err := command.Execute(ctx)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

However this code does NOT compile.
It yields the following error:

.\app.go:53:16: cannot use &rest.GetAPIKey literal (type *rest.GetAPIKey) as type commands.Command in argument to container.Add:
*rest.GetAPIKey does not implement commands.Command (wrong type for Execute method)
have Execute(rest.context) error
want Execute(commands.context) error

Is there any way to make this code work?
So the `context` interface is defined in 2 places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not work because the function signatures don't match. You can do:

- Make Context a shared interface, so every package can use it. This does not necessarily introduce dependencies between packages using it.
- Use context.Context, and expect to see the key in there. This is essentially the same as #1 but using a known predefined type
- Use interface{} instead of context, and use type assertion to convert it to the local context type.